# How to upgrade Cybersource compatible with SHA-2 Magento 1.6

Tags: payment

I have received email notifications from Cybersource saying in order to enhance security between server to server communication. They will move away from SHA-1 to SHA-2, does anyone know what I have to do for this upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

That's more than a bit concerning that they are just not moving from SHA-1. That should have been done over a year ago. Which extension are you using? I would contact the vendor and ask them if there is an update for their extension. Can you give more details about the email they sent?

Comment: thanks @PhilipDeatherage ! We have just migrated the existing project from previous dev, it looks like some custom module based on Core/Mage/Cybersource  on Magento 1.6.2.0
Could you let me have your email address then I can forward the email sent from the vendor if that is alright with you?

Comment: That is the core module that was released by Magento at one point. However, that's not supported anymore, but could of course be updated. pd @ dwdonline.com